# Laravel Eloquent: One to Many Accessor

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, accessor

How do I make One to Many Accessor ?

User Model :

```
public function histories()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\History');
}
```

History Model :

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

---

If I do like below, it will works.

User Model :

```
public function getHappyHistoryAttribute()
{
    return $this->products()->happyHistory()->first()->text;
}
```

History Model :

```
public function scopeHappyHistory(Builder $builder)
{
    return $builder->where(function (Builder $query) {
                return $query->where('status', 'happy');
            });
}
```

Controller :

```
public function show($id)
{
    return view("my_view", [
        'user' => User::find($id)
    ]);
}
```

Blade view :

```
{{ dd($user->happy_history) }}
```

**It works !**

---

But, How should I do if I want this :

```
{{ dd($user->histories->happy) }}
```

---

I try like

History Model :

```
public function scopeHappyHistory(Builder $builder)
{
    return $builder->where(function (Builder $query) {
                return $query->where('status', 'happy');
            });
}

public function getHappyAttribute()
{
    return $this->happyHistory->first()->text;
}
```

**It doesn't works !**

If I code like

```
{{ dd($user->histories->happy) }}
```

It will return

> ***Property [happy] does not exist on this collection instance.***

If I code like

```
{{ dd($user->histories()->happy) }}
```

It will return

> ***Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$happy***

**Correct me If I wrong**

Comment: What returns `dd($user->histories)` null or something

Comment: @A.ANoman it will works. it return the collection of the relation

Comment: You also try like this `$user->histories['happy']`

Comment: @A.ANoman make sense, I'll try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not work like that because the relationship is `oneToMany`.

Try following in your User model

```
/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function happyHistory()
{
    //Happy history is your scope form History model
    //Following will not get you first model
    return $this->histories()->happyHistory()->first();  
}
```

That will give you first model and then you can do following from User model

```
$user->happyHistory->text
```

Not tested but this should work.

Also you dont need to pass the query builder in scope. You can do following

```
public function scopeStatus($query, $status = "happy")
{
    return $query->where('status', $status);
}
```

Now you can use it for all `status` type.

```
History::status()->all(); //Will return all Happy history

History::status("sad")->all(); //Will return all Sad history
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It works, but I want find another option answer. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: What is wrong with this approach? So I can help you with different approach.